# Use De Moivre's theorem to prove that if $z=rcis(\theta)$ then $(z^*)^n=(z^n)^*$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Use De Moivre's theorem to prove that if $z=r\, \text{cis}(\theta)$ then
>   $(z^*)^n=(z^n)^*$

I think that I should write $z$ in the polar form: $z=r[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)]$. Then the conjugate will be $z^*=r[\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)]=r[\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)]$.

But how do I prove it? By induction or otherwise?

Comment: As $z\mapsto \bar z$ is an automorphism of ${\mathbb C}$ the formula $\bigl(\bar z\bigr)^n=\overline{z^n}$ holds for any $z\in{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: @Christian Blatter, but at some point you need to prove $\overline{z\cdot w} = \overline z\cdot\overline w$, no?

Comment: @Ennar: Of course; this is inherent in the notion of automorphism. – At any rate, the formula in question is true without any reference to the exponential function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand $$(z^*)^n=(rcis(-\theta))^n=r^n cis(-n\theta),$$ thanks to De Moivre's law. On the other hand $$(z^n)^* = (r^n cis(n\theta))^*=r^n cis (-n\theta).$$